# How to find a nearest line to a point

Tags: postgis, sql

I have a table with many points that need to be associated with street segments to calculate an average value. 
should I do a relationship for all points to a street segment that is closest. 
I have dealt with several queries but most is for a specific point with coordinates, I do take care for the whole set of points (61000), similar to the "spatial join" for proximity of ArcGIS

**Attributes of the streets** 
id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval ('calles_osm_gid_seq' :: regclass), 
objectid integer,     osm_id numeric,     name character varying       (48),     Inventory character varying (16),     type character       varying (16),     oneway smallint,     bridge smallint,     maxspeed     smallint,     shape_leng numeric,     maxvel integer,     MinSpd       smallint,     azimuth numeric,     geom geometry (MultiLineString,       4326),

**Point attributes** 
    "Latitude"numeric (50,10), 
   "Longitude" numeric (50,10), 
   "Azimuth" integer, 
   "Speed​​" integer, 
   "Date" timestamp without time zone, 
   "Geometry" geometry (Point, 4326), 
   id_calles integer

Any idea?

Comment: So you need a nearest line for each point? Or a line nearest to a set of points?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [algorithm to get the nearest line segment (link) to a point](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172677/algorithm-to-get-the-nearest-line-segment-link-to-a-point)

Answer (score 1):

If id_calles is your foregin key to streets table this could be resolution:

```
update point p
set id_calles = 
  (
  select s.id
  from streets s
  where st_dwithin(s.geom::geography, p.geometry::geography, 500) --in meters
  order by st_distance(s.geom, p.geometry)
  limit 1 
  )
```

If not please post some comment so I can improve it...