# Algorithm to get the nearest line segment (link) to a point

Tags: qgis, postgis, spatial-database

What is the fastest algorithm to get the nearest line segment to a point (that is not on any line segment) in a GIS database?

Comment: Do you mean to find the nearest line segment to a point?

Answer (score 4):

Using the [<#>](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_box.html) operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM point
CROSS JOIN line
WHERE [condition for the points];
ORDER BY point.geom <#> line.geom
LIMIT 1;
```

Make spatial index before running this query, to speed up.

```
Create index pnt_idx on point using GIST(geom);
Create index lin_idx on line using GIST(geom);`
```

Comment: You should use `<->` to return the real distance instead of the bounding box distance. And I think that `point.geom` will not be available inside the subquery. Better to do something like this: `select point.id from point, line order by point.geom <-> line.geom limit 1 `