# How to calculate nearest line from point using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have point data, which store the `"pharmacy_name"` field

I also have street data (as linestring), which store the `"street_name"` field.

I want to know which pharmacy is located on which street. How can I calculate this with a SQL query in PostGIS?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  As a new user please take the [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). We ask that all coding questions include code (in this case, your SQL so far). Unfortunately, the information you seek is not obvious from the data source, especially when you consider that pharmacies tend to be on corners.

Comment: This question may be useful for you. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42003/how-to-find-nearest-line-from-point-using-postgis

Comment: Possible duplicate of [algorithm to get the nearest line segment (link) to a point](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172677/algorithm-to-get-the-nearest-line-segment-link-to-a-point)